# How to change JBoss EAP 6.4 server log directory with server name in path?

Tags: logging, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I have two JVMs (server1 and server2) running on one Linux Machine. & I want to move logs from default directory to a custom directory for each JVM.

Something like -

```
/data/logs/$JVM_NAME/
```

so that final logs get to directories soemthing like

```
/data/logs/server1/
&
/data/logs/server2/
```

I learned that `jboss.server.log.dir` variable can be set in server startup arguments. Then I tried following startup command.

```
nohup sh /appl/isaac/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/domain.sh -b some.server.domain.com -bmanagement some.server.domain.com -Djboss.domain.log.dir=/data/logs -Djboss.server.log.dir=/data/logs/ > /tmp/domain.out 2>&1 &
```

This is working fine. And the logs are getting written in `/data/logs/`.

But I am not sure how to add a variable in these arguments to add one more sub directory with JVM name for each JVM on this machine. So that logs gets written to `/data/logs/$JVM_NAME/`.

Comment: Follow this for your answer --> [Change Custom log path in wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77711416/18152748)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an [issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-443) that was fixed in WildFly 9.

If you don't mind one extra directory you could get them into directories like `/data/logs/servers/server1` and `/data/logs/servers/server2`. To do this you just need to change the `directory-grouping` attribute on your host.

```
/host=master:write-attribute(name=directory-grouping, value=by-type)
```

Then just pass the system properties like you are in your command. You should end up with something like the following.

```
├── host-controller.log
├── process-controller.log
└── servers
    ├── server-one
    │   └── server.log
    └── server-two
        └── server.log
```

Comment: Can we use it for GC logs we well? I tried adding ${jboss.server.log.dir} to GC log file in JVM configuration but it doesn't seems to be working. Here is a snippet from VM Arguments: `-Xloggc:/data/logs//gc_%p_%t.log -Djboss.server.log.dir=/data/logs/servers/myserver_8180 ` I added JVM argument like : `-Xloggc:${jboss.server.log.dir}/gc_%p_%t.log`

Comment: I also tried `-Xloggc:${jboss.server.log.dir}/servers/${jboss.server.name}/gc_%p_%t.log` with no success.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work for GC logs. I don't think JVM parameters are processed for property replacement like that. It definitely won't work for the host controller or process controller GC logs.